# get changes on a git branch (NOT include changes due to lack of pulls)

Tags: git, diff

Say I've got a branch (called myBranch) on which I made some changes.

I know doing `git diff myBranch..master` will get me the *difference* between myBranch and master, but that diff also includes the differences which weren't caused *by me*. (ie., those could be changes that happened on master but which I haven't pulled to my branch, which I dont care about!)

Is there a quick way for me to get ONLY changes that I made on my branch against master?

Answer (score 0):

This will show you commits you've added to master but not to myBranch:

```
git log myBranch..master --author "$(git config user.name)"
```

This will show you commits you've added to myBranch but not to master:

```
git log master..myBranch --author "$(git config user.name)"
```

This will show you all commits in your branch that are not in master:

```
git log master..myBranch
```